# What type of data does string.byte return?

Tags: string, lua, byte

What type of data does `string.byte` return in this sample code:

```
s = string.byte("hello", 1, 6)
```

`type(s)` returns `"number"`, but why then does `print` output 6 numbers and not 1?

Comment: You should check the manual for the string.byte function. It will tell you why your example code returns six numbers. (Hint: That's what you asked for.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`string.byte`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-string.byte) returns multiple numbers, if you tell it to do so. The reason `print` is displaying five numbers instead of one is because it is capturing all of the return values, whereas with an assignment, only the first value is used and the rest are discarded.

```
local h = string.byte'hello' -- 104, returns only the first byte
local e = string.byte('hello', 2) -- 101, specified index of 2
local s = string.byte('hello', 1, 6) -- 104 101 108 108 111,
                                     -- but s is the only variable available,
                                     -- so it receives just 104
local a, b = string.byte('hello', 1, 6) -- same thing, except now there are two
                                        -- variables available, thus:
                                        -- a = 104 & b = 101
print(string.byte('hello', 1, 6))
```

```
104     101     108     108     111
```

```
print(string.byte('hello', 1, 6), 0) -- in this case, only the first value from
                                     -- the multiple return is used because there
                                     -- is another argument after the results
```

```
104     0
```

I'd suggest reading up on how multiple results and vararg expressions work in Lua.

> [***Lua Manual 3.4.10*** - **Function Definitions**](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.4.10)
>
> [...] If a vararg expression is used inside another expression or in the middle of a list of expressions, then its return list is adjusted to one element. If the expression is used as the last element of a list of expressions, then no adjustment is made (unless that last expression is enclosed in parentheses).

Answer (score 1):

The output is the ASCII code of the character - see http://www.asciitable.com/

You can use a for loop to iter if you want -

```
s = "hello";
for i=1,string.len(s) do print(string.byte(s,i)) end;
```

To turn them back into text, you can use string.char() --

```
s = "hello";
for i=1,string.len(s) do print(string.char(string.byte(s,i))) end;
```

you can look into using an array to work with the output:
http://www.lua.org/pil/11.1.html

```
s = "hello"; a = {};
for i=1,string.len(s) do a[i] = string.byte(s,i) end;
for i=1,table.getn(a) do print(a[i]) end;
```

Comment: Why the downvote...it wasn't totally useless...not as well done as Ryan's, but given the question to work with, I'd say it's not bad.

Comment: ASCII code? Probably not unless that's the source of your string. A Lua string is a counted sequence of bytes. `string.byte` simply returns part of that sequence. In this case, the data is a literal string in the script file so it's to the editor that saved it. In my case, it would UTF-8.

Comment: From above answer `104 101 108 108 111` ...was trying to explain what the output was, as the question asked `What type of data does string.byte return` and I was trying to explain what those numbers represent.  Anyway, the question is answered, that's all any of us want.  Moving on.